# How to process data from multiple results with enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want to get a UIImage and title from my object so I make a generic result with enum.

but I have an error while I try to take my result in completionHandler and an error while I called my **func fetchDataResult(for video: Video, completion: @escaping (Results<(UIImage?, String?)>) -> ())** in my controller. This is my code.

> Member 'success' in 'Results<(UIImage?, String?)>' produces result of type 'Results', but context expects 'Results<(UIImage?, String?)>'

```
enum Results<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}

class VideoStore {
    func fetchDataResult(for video: Video, completion: @escaping (Results<(UIImage?, String?)>) -> ()) {
        guard let videoKey = video.videoID else {
            preconditionFailure("Video expected to have a video id")
        }

        if let image = imageStore.image(forKey: videoKey) {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success((image, nil)))
            }
            return
        }

        guard let videoURL = video.url else {
            preconditionFailure("Video expected to have video url")
        }

        if let videoTitle = video.title {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success((nil, videoTitle)))
            }
        }

        let request = URLRequest(url: videoURL)

        let task = sessions.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            let result = self.processDataRequest(data: data, error: error)

            if case let .success(image) = result {
                self.imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: videoKey)
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success((result, nil)))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    private func processDataRequest(data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Results<UIImage> {
        guard
            let imageData = data,
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                if data == nil {
                    return .failure(error!)
                } else {
                    return .failure(ThumbnailError.thumbnailCreationError)
                }
            }
        return .success(image)
    }
}
```

This is my VideoController that have an error

> Cannot assign value of type '(UIImage?, String?)' to type 'UIImage?'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let video = videoDataSource.videos[indexPath.row]

        videoStore.fetchDataResult(for: video) { (results) in
            guard
                let videoIndex = self.videoDataSource.videos.firstIndex(of: video),
                case let .success(image) = results else { return }

            let photoIndexPath = IndexPath(item: videoIndex, section: 0)

            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: photoIndexPath) as? VideoCell {
                cell.videoImgView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `results` in the following line:

```swift
videoStore.fetchDataResult(for: video) { (results) in
```

has a type `(UIImage?, String?)`.
The completion handler for your `fetchDataResult` gets the type `Results<(UIImage?, String?)>` as you defined, which makes the `case success(Value)` to `case success((UIImage?, String?))`.

If you only need `UIImage?` from the value, you need to do

```swift
guard
  let videoIndex = self.videoDataSource.videos.firstIndex(of: video),
  case let .success(image, _) = results else { return }
```

Note that Swift has its own `Results` type since Swift 5.

Comment: hey for the case let it works, but what about the completion handler in my function fetchDataResult let task = sessions.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            let result = self.processDataRequest(data: data, error: error)

            if case let .success(image) = result {
                self.imageStore.setImage(image, forKey: videoKey)
            }
            
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                completion(.success((result, _)))
            }
        }
        task.resume()